# How to put NestedScrollView between LinearLayout and MaterialButton on ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This is the rough design of my activity:

[image]

On the top is a RelativeLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView. On the middle is a NestedScrollView which contains a RecyclerView and a CardView below it. And finally a Button on the bottom. Previously it's implemented in RelativeLayout, and works OK.

Then I change it into ConstraintLayout, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myapp_main_bg"
    tools:context=".activity.OrderConfirmationActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgForkDish"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fork_dish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgForkDish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Starbucks Senayan City" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnOrderNow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rlHeader"
        android:id="@+id/ns_recview_orders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlHeader"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recview_orders"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvPay"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/ns_recview_orders"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/row01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Payment Method"
                            android:id="@+id/tvLblPaymentMethod"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="e-wallet"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/v01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row01"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/row02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/v01"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvLblTotalOrder"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Total Order" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalOrder"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/row03"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Service Fee"
                            android:id="@+id/tvLblServiceFee"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/row04"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row03"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Total"
                            android:id="@+id/tvLblTotal"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:id="@+id/row05"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row04"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Include Tax"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnOrderNow"
        android:text="Order Now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/myapp_blue_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, the NestedScrollView isn't positioned below RelativeLayout, but instead overlaps it. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this tag from `NestedScrollView`:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

It is overlapping the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rlHeader"` tag.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't change the output, though...